# Open page depending on language

Tags: php, jquery, html

How can I change "textos legales" to for example "legal text" when I enter the english version of the so I can change the a href to a new "legal texts" in english?

This is what i´m using for the spanish version:

```
<li class="legal"><a href="/textos-legales">Textos legales</a></li>
```

Comment: Isn't this usually handled by the web server itself? [Apache can be set](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) to automatically redirect users to a subdirectory which is in the appropriate language, based on the browser's headers.

Comment: Agree with @Blazemonger.  You should do this on the server side (PHP) not in jQuery.  Every text string that might be presented in a local language should be a variable.  You then check the context of the page for what language you are in and swap the variable with the value of a langage table of some sort (could be an PHP array or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it depending on the users browser preferred language:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-negotiate-language.php

```
$languages = array(
        'en',// default
        'es',
);
$result = array();
$locale = http_negotiate_language($languages, $result);..

if($locale=="es"){
    echo "<li class='legal'><a href='/textos-legales'>Textos legales</a></li>";
}else{
    echo "<li class='legal'><a href='/legal'>legal text</a></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could grab the URI and if URI == en echo english text

```
$page=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($page == '/en'){
 echo 'Legal text';
}else if($page == '/es'){
 echo 'Textos legales';
}.....
```